# How to find the directory a device is mounted to?

Tags: linux, bash

In Linux, is it possible via a bash script to take '/dev/sr0' and determine what folder it's mounted to and perform extra actions on said folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output the directory name via this command:

```
grep /dev/sr0 /etc/mtab | cut "-d " -f2
```

or use it in other commands like this (e.g. list its contents):

```
ls $(grep /dev/sr0 /etc/mtab | cut "-d " -f2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `mount(8)` to find what device is mounted where. On Linux this information is found in the `/proc/mounts` file.